# How triple slash works in TypeScript for referencing

Tags: typescript

I'm beginner in typescript.

I made a [codesnippet](https://8wr0o.csb.app/) with two files, utils.ts and index.ts.

**utils.ts**

```
function theDate() {
  return new Date();
}
```

**index.ts**

```
/// <reference path="utils.ts" />
let t = theDate();
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h1>Hello Parcel!</h1>
<div>
  Look
  <a href="https://parceljs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">here</a>
  for more info about Parcel.
</div>
`;
```

I tried to reference the `theDate` function in utils.ts...

```
function theDate() {
  return new Date();
}
```

by adding the following to index.ts:

```
/// <reference path="utils.ts" />
```

but I get the following error:

> theDate is not defined

Isn't triple reference ([TypeScript docs reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)) supposed to be able to fix this issue?

Comment: By chance to do you have the [--noresolve](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) flag set to `true` in your compiler options?

Comment: no I don't have. I have only "compilerOptions" with target and libs in vscode tsconfig file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after another peek I think I know your culprit. Generally the triple slash is if you're looking to ref type definitions `blah.d.ts` or looking to throw the `--out` flag on compile.

I think what you're actually wanting to do in your scenario you would change your method to;

```
export function theDate() {
  return new Date();
}
```

Then where you wish to utilize it you would include an import with designation for tree shaking purposes at the top with other import declaration via;

```
import { theDate} from 'path/to/file/or/using/alias/to/find/utils';
```

Then use as expected;

```
BlahMethod = (something) => {

   something.value = theDate;

}
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: thanks it works. but I'm still frustrated that it doesn't work with /// according to help it should have worked ;) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

Comment: I can only speak of personal opinion but I'm not a fan of them most of the time anyway since on compile say for instance that util file has a hundred methods, say only one is ever used, that whole file still gets appended to the bundle, where as the direct import will just pull what's specified. Either way glad you got a remedy!

Comment: Yes I have read it's not good practice but I like to understand when things don't work whereas they're supposed to according to official help :)

Comment: Can't say for sure, would have to see the proj details like tsconfig etc and poke at it.